# How to put CSS documentation in Netbeans

Tags: css, netbeans, javafx, documentation

I am busy working on a JavaFX Project and am using CSS for style.
When editing the css file I noticed that my IDE didn't have any documentation about the functions.
So I browsed the plugin tab with no result.

Googled and didn't even find some topic about CSS documentation in an IDE .
(with the exception about the Eclipse IDE ,but I am using Netbeans).

So I'm kinda lost ,can anyone give me some directions to look at?

Thank you

Comment: AFAIK, the JavaFX CSS support is only provided by the e(fx)clipse pluging in Eclipse !

Comment: Do you think it would be a lot of work to modify it to a Netbeans plugin ?

Comment: Well, I have written a plugin, either for Eclipse or for Netbeans, so I am not sure. But, if you can, it would be a great addition to Netbeans ! :)

Comment: I think I'd be a bit in over my head ,from the looks of it.  Maybe when I start to learn XML I'll have another look.:p

Comment: Have you add fx documentation to your Netbeans?

Comment: Yes I do alrdy have fx docu

Answer (score 0):

Add Java Fx documentation to your Netbeans:

1. In your Netbeans, click Tools >> JavaPlatforms
2. Choose Javadoc tab
3. Add URL, http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/

Note:

- You may need Internet connection to access the documentation.
- You can add another documentation by same directions with different URL.
- You can add Zip/file if you already downloaded / had the documentation.

Comment: This will only add documentations for JavaFX classes and methods, but not for JavaFX CSS.